# TemplateDoesNotExist error in Django version 2.0.2

Tags: django, django-templates, python-3.5

[My Django project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hS5a.png)

The codes are:

settings.py is:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        # 'DIRS': ['templates', ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'python_django_blog',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Coder123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

from first import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('post-list/', views.postlist, name='post-list'),
]
```

views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .models import Post

def postlist(request):
    all_post=Post.objects.all()
    # return render(request,'post_list.html', all_post)
    return render_to_string(request,'post_list.html', {'all_post_list': all_post})
```

post_list.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oh No</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Problem and problem</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[Problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5XKv.png)

I think, all the settings are alright. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ also works fine. But I'm getting errors entering http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-list/. I've searched many question similar to this. After fixing, I've made the above codes. But those codes shows errors. I cannot figure out what the problem is. Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'first/templates')],

Comment: In views.postlist method, I've replaced render_to_string method with render. And this works now.